# Ninject Fails On FTP, Runs at local

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

i have serious problem with my project. My Project runs successfuly on my local machine. But when i publish and upload project into FTP, i get This Error;

> Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject, Version=3.3.4.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' or one of its
> dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
>
> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject,
> Version=3.3.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' or
> one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an
> assembly manifest.]
> RefectoryAutomation.WebUI.Infrastructure.Ninject.NinjectControllerFactory..ctor()
> in
> E:\v1.250220.01-RefectoryAutomation\RefectoryAutomation.WebUI\Infrastructure\Ninject\NinjectControllerFactory.cs:16
> RefectoryAutomation.WebUI.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in
> E:\v1.250220.01-RefectoryAutomation\RefectoryAutomation.WebUI\Global.asax.cs:64
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject,
> Version=3.3.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' or
> one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an
> assembly manifest.]
> System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
> context, HttpApplication app) +546
> System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
> appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +171
> System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
> MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +173
> System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
> appContext, HttpContext context) +255
> System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
> appContext) +347
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject,
> Version=3.3.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' or
> one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an
> assembly manifest.]
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +552
> System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
> +122    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
> wr, HttpContext context) +737

What did i tried?

1. I uninstall and install Ninject and other depended libraries.
2. i fixed dependentAssembly version in webconfig file
3. I check and fix package.config file
4. I delete bin folder and rebuild thousand times

I made a lot of things... nothing works.

**My Web Config File (Web UI Layer)**

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.4.0" newVersion="3.3.4.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

**My Package Config File (Web UI Layer)**

```
<package id="Ninject" version="3.3.4.0" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="net452" />
```

**MY App Config file (Business Layer)**

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Ninject" publicKeyToken="c7192dc5380945e7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.3.4.0" newVersion="3.3.4.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

**My Package Config File (Business Layer)**

```
 <package id="Ninject" version="3.3.4.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Ninject.Extensions.Conventions" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Ninject.Extensions.Factory" version="3.3.3" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Is there any solution for this? I couldn't find any answer. All advices are failed.

Comment: Does ninject.dll actually get deployed? Does your server have .net 4.52 installed? Check the server event viewer.

Comment: App.config files from libraries you consume don't matter. Only app.config files from the executing app (or web.config for ASP.NET) actually matter.

Comment: Why do you have binding redirects in place? Do you have multiple versions of Ninject in your app?